# How to select rows where field is not blank/empty

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a MySQL query in phpMyAdmin. I want to find an entry where fieldone is not NULL or is not empty/blank as I inherited the system so fields are set to NULL and some are just blank.

Anyways, Here is the query I'm trying

```
SELECT fieldone, fieldtwo
FROM tableone
WHERE fieldone != ' '
OR fieldone IS NOT NULL
```

And

```
SELECT fieldone, fieldtwo
FROM tableone
WHERE fieldone <> ' '
OR fieldone IS NOT NULL
```

Both show an error #1064 on the line that contains

```
WHERE fieldone != ' '
```

And

```
WHERE fieldone <> ' '
```

The NOT NULL part works great, its just trying to find any fields that are blank.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT fieldone, fieldtwo
FROM tableone
WHERE fieldone != ''
OR fieldone IS NOT NULL

SELECT fieldone, fieldtwo
FROM tableone
WHERE fieldone <> ''
OR fieldone IS NOT NULL
```

When you mean NULL value then don't include a space between your '' so it means NO CONTENT

Comment: Now it says #1054 - Unknown column '‘’' in 'where clause' and the field is defianlty the right name, i have triple checked

Comment: Try this only 
SELECT fieldone, fieldtwo
FROM tableone
WHERE fieldone != ''

Comment: That means there is a column not existing in the table you are selecting. Ensure there are no mis-spelling of your table columns

Comment: Using double quotes rather than single seemed to work, thanks for the help.

Comment: I think there should be "AND" instead of "OR" :   
 WHERE fieldone != '' AND fieldone IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 6):

You could try this:

```
SELECT fieldone, fieldtwo 
FROM tableone 
WHERE fieldone IS NOT NULL 
AND TRIM(fieldone) <> ''
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is just below (If filedone is NULL, it won't be in the result set):

**Everything compared with `NULL` is still `NULL`**

```
SELECT fieldone, fieldtwo
FROM tableone
WHERE fieldone != ''
```